# Unable to open httpConnection in Jetty9 while migrating from jetty6

Tags: jetty-9, httpconnection

I am migrating my current spring based java project from jetty6 to jetty9. I am also migrating from JDK6 to JDK9 at the same time. I do understand that quite a lot has changed with jetty.
I tried to follow the docs from jetty link but after successfully building my project I am getting error while trying to open active http/https connections.

I have done the configuration in XML as I am reading a lot of values from properties file and doing all this programmatically won't be very clean approach.

Below is my configuration:-

```
<Configure id="server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
<New id="httpConfig"
        class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
        <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
        <Set name="securePort"><Ref id="opPort" /></Set>
        <Set name="outputBufferSize">32768</Set>
        <Set name="requestHeaderSize">8192</Set>
        <Set name="responseHeaderSize">8192</Set>
        <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
        <Set name="sendDateHeader">false</Set>
        <Set name="headerCacheSize">512</Set>
        <Call name="addCustomizer">
            <Arg>
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer" />
            </Arg>
        </Call>
    </New>
<Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <Arg name="server">
                    <Ref refid="server" />
                </Arg>
<!--                <Arg name="acceptors">2</Arg> -->
<!--                <Arg name="selectors">-1</Arg> -->
                <Arg name="factories">
                    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                        <Item>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                                <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
                                <Arg name="sslContextFactory">
                                    <Ref refid="sslContextFactory" />
                                </Arg>
                            </New>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                                <Arg name="config">
                                    <Ref refid="httpConfig" />
                                </Arg>
                            </New>
                        </Item>
                    </Array>
                </Arg>
                <Set name="host">localhost</Set>
                <Set name="port">
                    <Ref id="opPort" />
                </Set>
                <Set name="idleTimeout">2000000</Set>
                <Set name="acceptQueueSize">64</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
<New id="sslContextFactory"
        class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
        <Set name="keyStorePath">./configuration/dev/keystore</Set>
        <Set name="keyStorePassword">OBF:1zlu1uum1toq1w8v1to41uvk1zlo</Set>
        <Set name="keyManagerPassword">OBF:1zlu1uum1toq1w8v1to41uvk1zlo</Set>
        <Set name="trustStorePath">./configuration/dev/keystore</Set>
        <Set name="trustStorePassword">OBF:1zlu1uum1toq1w8v1to41uvk1zlo</Set>
<!--        <Set name="endpointIdentificationAlgorithm"></Set> -->
        <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
            <Array type="String">
                <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5</Item>
                <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
            </Array>
        </Set>
    </New>
<Set name="handler">
        <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
            <Set name="handlers">
                <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
                    <!--your web app WAR goes here -->
                    <Item>
                        <New id="WmSecurityWebApp" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                            <Arg>./target/gls-op.war</Arg>
                            <Arg>/gls-op/us/7049</Arg>
                            <Set name="logUrlOnStart"  type="boolean">true</Set>
<Set name="parentLoaderPriority">true</Set>
</New>
                    </Item>
</Array>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Set>
```

While the project is building successfully but when I hit any Rest API, it throws error:-

```
16:26:16.470 [qtp985922955-32] DEBUG o.e.j.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - ran EatWhatYouKill@29855e88/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@dcd6f19/PRODUCING/1/1
16:26:16.470 [qtp985922955-18] DEBUG o.e.jetty.server.HttpConnection -
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:804) ~[jetty-io-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
```

I have updated the keystore using jdk8 and also the OBF form using jetty utility version being used on my machine.

Even after changing many things around, it is not working out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I removed SSL and tested only using HTTP connection settings. It worked fine. I am not using SSL for now and it seems to be good for now. Meanwhile I will keep checking out for options to use both settings together in a single file.